# Focus pseudo-class in Material ui

Tags: material-ui, jss

I am trying to apply some styles when a material-ui form control gets focus.

The pseudo-class 'hover' works well in the code below but 'focus' does not.

I am assuming that clicking into the Input component gives it focus but that does not seem to work. Any idea why and how to make it work?

```
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles"
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input"
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel"
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl"


const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        border: "1px solid",
        borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
        borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23)",
        marginBottom: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        padding: theme.spacing.unit,
        width: "100%",
        display: "flex",
        flexDirection: "row",
        alignItems: "center",
        "&:focus": {
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        }
    }
})


class TagsComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <FormControl variant="outlined">
                <InputLabel>Tags</InputLabel>
                <Input
                    disableUnderline
                    classes={{
                        root: this.props.classes.root
                    }}
                />
            </FormControl>
        )
    }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(TagsComponent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply styles by overriding styles for input or override class name `focused`

```
const styles = {
 ...,
 focused: {
   backgroundColor: "green"
 },
 input: {
    "&:focus": {
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      color: "white"
    }
  }
}

 <Input
    disableUnderline
    classes={{
        root: classes.root,
        focused: classes.focused,
        input: classes.input
    }}
 />
```

Sandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/gallant-pascal-rh8jc

Comment: Perfect! Got what I needed :D